# Get unique connection id in client in Websocket

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket

I'm new to WebSocket and would like to make a notification feature whenever there's a message send from an user. I figured I need the unique id of each connection to shows the notification to all users except the sender.

I have the following simple code in the backend, written in Spring:

```
 private final List<WebSocketSession> webSocketSessions = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
    webSocketSessions.add(session);
    super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
}

@Override
protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
    for (WebSocketSession webSocketSession : webSocketSessions) {
        webSocketSession.sendMessage(message);
    }
}

@Override
public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
    webSocketSessions.remove(session);
}
```

And my client code (written in Angular):

```
 public openWebSocket() {
    this.webSocket = new WebSocket(environment.wsUrl + '/chat');
    this.webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log(this.webSocket);
      console.log('Open ', event);
    }

    this.webSocket.onmessage = (event) => {
      const newMessage = JSON.parse(event.data);
      this.chatMessages.push(newMessage);
    }

    this.webSocket.onclose = (event) => {
      console.log('Close ', event);
    }
}
```

How would I achieve such purpose? Sorry this question might be unclear but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Just send it to all but the current session.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: And do I send it from the front or back end?

Comment: In your loop, continue if `session == webSocketSession `, otherwise send.

Comment: That could work, but I need the message to display to the sender as well, whenever they send a new message.

Comment: Eh? Your question specifically says 'all users except the sender'. Make up your mind. If what you want is what it says in the question, use my comment. If what you want is what it says in your comment, you're already dong it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226697/discussion-between-user545871-and-user207421).